# Need Sorting on both ASC and DESC using collection sort for List based on single object value

Tags: java, collections

List contains object values 
For Example:

```
Object obj1=new Object();
obj.setName("Yoga");
obj.setCountry("India);
obj.setZIPCode(600000);
obj.setName("Ram");
obj.setCountry("Malaysia);
obj.setZIPCode(400000);

List<Object> L1 = new ArrayList(object);
L1.add(obj.getName);
L1.add(obj.getCountry);
L1.add(obj.getZIPCode);
```

Need Output is based on the single variable **country**.
Need to order as ascending and descending.

```
Collections.sort(list ,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

The above code will be used as generic sort of the whole list but I need as customized sort based on country.

**Output:**

```
**Name      Country         ZIPCode**
Yoga      India           600000
Ram       Malaysia        400000
```

Kindly help on this sorting using collection sort.

Comment: You should be able to solve this after reading through the [Object Ordering tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). Hint: write a custom `Comparator` and pass it to `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

A Comparator is a class that defines a custom sorting algorithm for a class.
Here is an example which compares based on the "country" attribute:

```
public class AddressComparator implements Comparator<Address> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Address o1, Address o2) {
        return o1.getCountry().compareTo(o2.getCountry());
    }        
}
```

You could write two different comparators, one for sorting in ascending order and a second for sorting in a descending one.